# Azure App Service - Memory errors after deploy from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, iis, memory, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

We have a web application running in a premium app service plan. Memory usage is between 15 and 20%. After every deploy we're having problems. We get a lot of out of memory errors and other weird errors, probably also memory related, even though the Azure Portal reports that we only use less than 20% most of the time.

If we do a restart of the application, the problems go away.

Any suggestions on how to find the root cause?

The process explorer i Kudu reports 4200 handles. Most of them are to static files like this:
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\appservicename\DynamicCache\wwwroot\histories\2018\assets\7DoLWBGPjU

Or to SnapshotDebuggerMetadataCache

C:\DWASFiles\Sites\appservicename\Temp\SnapshotDebuggerMetadataCache\22376\9abb1665-ef45-41d9-8b8c-e610ff76f2e9

Could this be related to the issue? Or can it be related to Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say, but I don't believe snapshot or dynamic cache has anything to do with deployment. I would check the deployment [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files) at ***your-app-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments*** to see if anything looks strange or out of place. Since your deployments are resulting in some weird memory issues, to circumvent that, I would look at [deploying to a slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-best-practices#use-deployment-slots) instead and then swap the slots once you're ready.

I would also check memory usage under the [Diagnostics and solve problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) blade to see which processes are consuming the most memory and collect a trace or dump of that particular process.